# how get the last directory using perl?

Tags: perl

I use below script to get the last directory.

```
my $bsnap = bla_path 
my $numbsnaps = defaultstr(some_file);
my (%snapshotdirs, $lastsnap);
if ($numbsnaps > 0) {
    system(@mkdir, '-vp', "$backupsnap/$bserver");
    exit 1 if checkrc("mkdir $backupsnap/$bserver:", $?, $!);
    unless(opendir($fh, "$backupsnap/$bserver")) {
        print STDERR "error: failed to open snapshot dir: $!\n";
        goto snapshot_end;
    }
    foreach $lastsnap (sort(grep({$_ !~ /^\.\.?$/ and -d "$backupsnap/$bserver/$_";} readdir($fh)))) {
        my $day = $lastsnap;
        $day =~ s/-\d+$//;
        push(@{$snapshotdirs{$day}}, $lastsnap);
    }
    if ($lastsnap) {
        $lastsnap = "$backupsnap/$bserver/$lastsnap";
    } else {
        $lastsnap = "$backupstore/$bserver" unless $lastsnap;
    }
    system(@mkdir, '-vp', "$bsnap");
    exit 1 if checkrc("mkdir $bsnap:", $?, $!);
}
```

But when I print `$lastsnap` I only get `$backupstore/$bserver`. I want to get `$backupsnap/$bserver/$lastsnap`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you expect `$lastsnap` in `if ($lastsnap)` (right after the `foreach` loop) to be?  After the loop it picks up the value it had before it, which is `undef`.  Thus it goes to `else` and you get what you report.

Comment: Hi @zdim it should pick the recently created  dir which named by timestamps,

Comment: when i comment out if else part i get
"Use of uninitialized value $lastsnap in print" so probably sort thing does not work

Comment: After the `foreach $lastsnap (sort ...` loop the `$lastsnap` variable is again what it was before that loop, so `undef` here.  So when the code comes to `if ($lastsnap) { ... } else ...` since `$lastsnap` is false (`undef`) it goes to `else`.

Comment: I still don't understand what you expect `$lastsnap` to be at that point -- if you expect it to be the last thing in `$snapshotdirs` data structure then you can set it up to that value, `$lastsnap = ...` right after the `foreach` loop

Comment: yes its the last dir in $snapshotdirs

Comment: Try this (on the command line): `perl -wE'my $v = 77;  for $v (1..3) { say "in loop: $v" };  say "After loop: $v"'`.  After the loop that `$v` is what it was before (77).  In your case that is `undef`.  So after the `foreach` loop you should set `$lastsnap` to what you need it to be

Comment: I would also suggest that you change the name of that variable inside the loop to something else -- because it is different from `$lastsnap` outside the loop (so that it's not confusing)

Comment: In short, `for $var (...)` (as opposed to `for my $var (...)`) makes no sense

Comment: "_yes its the last dir in `$snapshotdirs`_" --- that we can't get since you add dirs to an arrayref _in a hash_, and hash is unordered (no way to tell what the last one was).  Then, if you  need the last one, record them: `my $last_dir; foreach my $ls (...) { $last_dir = $ls; .... }` (I replaced the name `$lastsnap` with `$ls`) and now after the loop the `$last_dir` has it.

Answer (score 4):

A few things that may help:

- Perl has a built-in [mkdir](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/mkdir.html)
- The File::Path core module has [make_path](https://perldoc.perl.org/File/Path.html) to do what `mkdir -vp` does

As for `$lastsnap`, you declare it outside of the `if` but don't assign it anything. Inside the loop you use it as the control variable with `foreach`, but try to access it afterward. That's not going to work because the control variable is private to that foreach loop. It temporarily masks a variable of the same name until the loop completes.

```
my $lastsnap;
print "1. \$lastsnap is $lastsnap\n";

foreach $lastsnap ( 0..2 ) {
    print "$lastsnap is $lastsnap\n";
    }

print "2. \$lastsnap is $lastsnap\n";
```

It ends up with `undef` after the loop even though its last value in the loop was 2:

```
1. $lastsnap is
0 is 0
1 is 1
2 is 2
2. $lastsnap is
```

Try it with an initial value:

```
my $lastsnap = 'foo';
print "1. \$lastsnap is $lastsnap\n";

foreach $lastsnap ( 0..2 ) {
    print "$lastsnap is $lastsnap\n";
    }

print "2. \$lastsnap is $lastsnap\n";
```

It ends up with the original value when the loop finishes because the `foreach`'s control variable no longer masks it:

```
1. $lastsnap is foo
0 is 0
1 is 1
2 is 2
2. $lastsnap is foo
```

When you check `$lastsnap` with the `if`, it's false so it does the `else` branch:

```
if ($lastsnap) {
    $lastsnap = "$backupsnap/$bserver/$lastsnap";
} else {
    $lastsnap = "$backupstore/$bserver" unless $lastsnap;
}
```

In the `else` branch you already know that `$lastsnap` is false but you check it again with `unless`. No big whoop, but this is where you assign it the value that you observe.

I don't have a particular fix for you because I can't quite tell what you are trying to do.